# testng repeat invocations by time period

Tags: testng

My manager asks me to run some kind of performance and stability test for a predefined time period.

This means, repeatedly running same set of tests, measuring various events until some predefined time period passes. That is his requirement.

For now, I am solving this by specifying an `invocationCount` on various methods involved. However, it becomes increasingly difficult to manage, since new methods are added, part of them running in parallel or using parallel data providers, and part of them depending on others. Also, the system under test has an asynchronous behavior, sometimes responding faster and sometimes slower. Hence the total execution time, especially for long time running executions becomes more and more difficult to predict, and even to calculate.

I am looking for something like `invocationCount` but with a time flavor. When specified it should repeat invoking like `invocationCount` does as long as there is remaining time left. Anyone did something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a high-level here's what you would need to do, to achieve this:

1. Create a custom annotation that can be used to state, how many iterations to run and for what duration.
2. Now for all test methods that need this capability, annotate them with the custom annotation defined in (1).
3. Define a base class which implements the TestNG interface `org.testng.IHookable`.
4. Within the `run()` method, parse the annotation and then use an executor service to control the duration and the iterations.

The custom annotation

```java
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD})
public @interface Repeatable {

  int forSeconds() default 0;

  int iterations() default 1;
}
```

The base class (This is needed only if you have multiple such test classes with the same need)

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

public class AbstractTestCase implements IHookable {

  @Override
  public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
    Repeatable repeatable =
        testResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(Repeatable.class);
    if (repeatable == null) {
      callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
      return;
    }
    Callable<Void> task =
        () -> {
          for (int i = 1; i <= repeatable.iterations(); i++) {
            System.err.println("Running iteration : " + i);
            callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
          }
          return null;
        };
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    try {
      List<Future<Void>> result =
          service.invokeAll(
              Collections.singletonList(task), repeatable.forSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      service.shutdown();
      result.forEach(
          r -> {
            try {
              r.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
          });
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

The test class

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassSample extends AbstractTestCase {

  @Test
  @Repeatable(forSeconds = 5, iterations = 10)
  public void runTask() throws InterruptedException {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    System.err.println("Woke up after sleeping for 1 second");
  }
}
```

Execution output

```
Running iteration : 1
Woke up after sleeping for 1 second
Running iteration : 2
Woke up after sleeping for 1 second
Running iteration : 3
Woke up after sleeping for 1 second
Running iteration : 4
Woke up after sleeping for 1 second
Running iteration : 5
Running iteration : 6



java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at com.rationaleemotions.AbstractTestCase.lambda$run$1(AbstractTestCase.java:42)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at com.rationaleemotions.AbstractTestCase.run(AbstractTestCase.java:39)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:255)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:594)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:821)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:588)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1214)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1136)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1066)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1034)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)


===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```